# Account List Not Being Sorted in Descending Order Using Wrapper Class

Tags: apex, developer

I have been learning Apex in the last few months using different platforms to do Apex Challenges. I am currently working on a challenge where the List Account has to be sorted in descending order, but I have been successful on this and I have been looking in a lot of resources what I am doing wrong but still not finding the right answer, and I hope that you guys could help me. Here is my current code:

```
public List<Account> getAccounts(List<Account> accounts) {

List<AccountWrapper> accWrapper = new List<AccountWrapper>();

for(AccountWrapper aWrap : accWrapper)
{
    Account account = new Account();

    account.Name = aWrap.acc.Name;
    account.AnnualRevenue = aWrap.acc.AnnualRevenue;
    accounts.add(account);
}
accWrapper.sort();
return accounts;
}

public class AccountWrapper implements Comparable
{
    public Account acc;
    public Decimal annualRevenue;

public AccountWrapper(Account act)
{
    acc = act;
    annualRevenue = act.AnnualRevenue;
}

public Integer compareTo(Object o)
{
    AccountWrapper otherAcc = (AccountWrapper)o;

    if(annualRevenue > acc.AnnualRevenue)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(annualRevenue < acc.AnnualRevenue)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
}
```

Here is an image of what is tested when I ran the code and is only the sorting order that I am getting still wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The method that implements Comparable is miscoded

You have:

```
   if(annualRevenue > acc.AnnualRevenue)    {
      return 1;
   }
   else if(annualRevenue < acc.AnnualRevenue)    {
      return -1;
   }
   return 0;
 
}
```

This compares the current wrapper object's `annualRevenue` against the current wrapper's `acc.AnnualRevenue`.

Instead, I surmise you want to compare

```
o.AnnualRevenue > this.annualRevenue etc.
```

Comment: Ps. You don't need to return -1, 0, 1. Just return the result of subtracting the current instance to the incoming data: `return annualRevenue - otherAcc.annualRevenue`